# Adding fade/transition to slider

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm in the process of using only javascript for a slideshow.. and [here's what I currently have](http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/slideshow3.html), my problem is, how do I make the image transition smoothly or like a fade effect? also is this the shortest possible javascript code for an automatic slideshow with caption? thanks!

Comment: If I may suggest, use this jquery plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

Jquery effects should sove your problem

[Effects API](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

[Effects Wiki](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [jquery slideshow plugin](http://www.cincopa.com/media-platform/jquery-slideshow), it has different styles of transition.